# Cannot get the chat timestamp to update automatically

Tags: javascript

I have the following code and cannot get the chat timestamp to update without refresh. I am new to javascript.

```js
function timeSince(date) {
    var seconds = Math.floor((new Date() - date) / 1000);

    var interval = seconds / 31536000;

    if (interval > 1) {
      return Math.floor(interval) + " years";
    }
    interval = seconds / 2592000;
    if (interval > 1) {
      return Math.floor(interval) + " months";
    }
    interval = seconds / 86400;
    if (interval > 1) {
      return Math.floor(interval) + " days";
    }
    interval = seconds / 3600;
    if (interval > 1) {
      return Math.floor(interval) + " hours";
    }
    interval = seconds / 60;
    if (interval > 1) {
      return Math.floor(interval) + " minutes";
    }
    return Math.floor(seconds) + " seconds";
  }
  setInterval(timeSince, 1000);
  var aDay = 24*60*60*1000;
  console.log(timeSince(new Date(Date.now()-aDay)));
  console.log(timeSince(new Date(Date.now()-aDay*2)));

  const dates = new Date(message.timestamp)

  if (message.user === currentUser) position = 'right';
  const messageItem = `

          <div class="message ${position}">
          <span class="small">${timeSince(dates)}</span><br>
```

I tried:   `setInterval(timeSince, 1000);` and   `setInterval(timeSince(), 1000);` and   `setInterval(timeSince(date, 1000);` and tried each in different place within the function, can't get to work.

Answer (score 1):

`timeSince` just returns your formatted string with the duration. Setting an interval on this function will do practically nothing. You have to use the return value.

```
setInterval(function(){
    var time = timeSince(message.timestamp); 
    //You can use a better selector here, 
    //but without more information, this is the best I can do.
    document.getElementsByClassName("small")[0].innerHTML = time;
}, 1000);
```

Comment: Thank you for your input. I tried it but still not working. i kept all as is and changed what you suggested. Maybe i should have pointed that all the attached above is a code inside a .js file. in the html they are called within a div with class "messages".
the rest of the above code ends as follows:
...... messageItem = `<div class="message ${position}">
 <span class="small">${timeSince(dates)}</span><br>
<div class="text_wrapper">
 <div class="text">${message.body}
  </div> </div></div>`;
    $(messageItem).appendTo('#messages');
appreciate you patience

Comment: and   <script src="{% static 'chats/app.js' %}"></script> which where the code is is placed at the bottomof the html file

Comment: i think the issue after updating to your suggestion is within the console.log but can't figure it out

Answer (score 0):

found a half solution. I had to insert the setInterval under the function that calls the function under which sits the timesince function. Now the whole thing updates after the interval i set and not just the time, but setting an update interval of 1 minute makes it fine with me.
Apparently since I have several functions under one, the setInterval doesn't work, or didn't work in my case.
draw message is the function under which the timeSince function resides
Maybe coz i didn't provide this info here before i didn't get the right help
Solution:
this:

```
function getConversation(recipient) {
  setInterval(function(){
    $.getJSON(`/api/v1/message/?target=${recipient}`, function (data) {
        messageList.children('.message').remove();
        for (let i = data['results'].length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            drawMessage(data['results'][i]);
        }

        messageList.animate({scrollTop: messageList.prop('scrollHeight')});
    });

}, 60000);}
```

or this:

```
  function getConversation(recipient) {
        $.getJSON(`/api/v1/message/?target=${recipient}`, function (data) {
            messageList.children('.message').remove();
            for (let i = data['results'].length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                drawMessage(data['results'][i]);
            }
            **setInterval(getConversation(recipient), 1000);**
            messageList.animate({scrollTop: messageList.prop('scrollHeight')});
        });
    
    }
```

Thank you David for your help